# How to reverse a repeated image on blogger

Tags: css, background-image

I can't believe I can't find this ANYWHERE, but I'm just wondering if anyone knew how to inversely repeat an image in blogger. For example, I'm using this CSS coding for a background image

```
body { background: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-yqiPjoMManc/UprceV8zY7I/AAAAAAAADZw/GP119GZKgzM/s1600/new+background.png) repeat fixed top center; background-color: none; }
.body-fauxcolumn-outer div { background: none !important; }
```

anyway, it looks super weird on screens of bigger computers, as you can see here: http://prntscr.com/292k6l

as when you repeat the image, the sides don't match up at all. Does anyone know how to continously flip around an image in blogger when repeated? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try cut pattern separately from the gradient and put them on different layers. If you give PSD i can help you. Gradient will stretch across the width of the page, the picture is repeated over the gradient.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! I did it myself, though thanks for the offer. Really helpful!